# How to add custom font at wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

The source of the font is: `/htdocs/wp-content/themes/elegance/fonts/pizza.otf`

I add to CSS(style.css):

```
 @font-face {
    font-family:'Pizza';
    src: url('fonts/narkis.otf');
}
```

And add also:

```
html,body,div,form,fieldset,input,textarea,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,ul,ol,li{
vertical-align:baseline;font-size:100%;padding:0;margin:0;font-family:'Pizza';
}
```

Its not working..

Comment: open the Developers Panel (F12) and find the classes / ids of items on which you want to apply the font and in `style.css` of the Child-Theme, target those classes

Comment: @emad i did that, its not working..